# Alinear verticalmente tablas HTML en 2 columnas

Tags: html, css

Mi problema son las 2 tablas de la **Izquierda**, las cuales quisiera que quedaran juntas como las de la **Derecha** y así aprovechar el espacio marcado de azul:

[image: reporte]

**¿Cómo puedo hacer que la tabla de abajo se pegue a la de arriba y no donde acabe la tabla de la otra columna?**

Código CSS para agrupar todas las tablas:

```
.tables-container{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            
        }
```

La estructura de las tablas:

```
<div class="tables-container">
    <table  border="1" width="40%">
    </table>
    <table  border="1" width="55%">
    </table>
    <table  border="1" width="40%">
    </table>
    <table  border="1" width="40%">
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estaría mucho mejor si das más detalles. ¿Usas Bootstrap? ¿Por qué no pones el código completo para ver las tablas y analizar mejor? Por ahora solo se me ocurre esto en tu CSS:

```
table td, table td * {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que haría yo seria separarlos por 2 columnas y ahí recién integrar las tablas, acá te dejo el código de lo que yo haría:

```css
.tables-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
.container-column {
    width: 49%;
   
}
.container-table {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables-container">
    <div class="container-column">
        <div class="container-table" style="height: 200px;">
            <table  border="1"  >
                a
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="container-table" style="height: 100px;">
            <table  border="1">
                b
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="container-table" style="height: 100px;">
            <table  border="1">
                c
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-column">
        
        <div class="container-table" style="height: 300px;">
            <table  border="1">
                d
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="container-table" style="height: 100px;">
            <table  border="1">
                f
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, suerte!